# Python, Selenium Action Chains Performing Extra Task

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

The purpose of my program is to use action keys in selenium to click on a URL (in an iframe) on the parent_window, open the clicked URL in a new tab, close the tab once data has been scraped, and then open the next URL to be scraped. The problem is that, once I try to open the second URL it opens that URL along with the one previously opened, resulting in 2 tabs being opened instead of 1. I am on Google Chrome.

```
x = 0
parent_window = driver.current_window_handle

while x < len(url_list): #Going through the URLs on the parent_window
    time.sleep(1)

#(ERROR, OPENING UP 2 TABS once x = 1)
    actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).click(url_list[x]).perform()

    #Scrape name and consideration amount
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[x+1])
    last_name.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/font"))
    first_name.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/table[3]/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/font"))
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(parent_window)
    driver.switch_to.frame("frmeSearchForm")
    
    x = x+1
```

Comment: What is the puspose of using ActionChains? Why not just making a `click()`?

Comment: @vitaliis I decided to go with your recommendation and click into every website instead of opening up a new tab. Thank you!

Comment: Good to know.  I could better answer your question if I saw your html code.